# Please explain the output of replace for regex in java script

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I'm having difficulty in understanding the output for the following use of replace in javascript for strings using regex. Please explain the value of 'temp' that will persist.

```
{
    var temp='xxxx5678';
    var format='x-$2';
    temp= temp.replace(/(x*)([0-9]+)/, format);
    console.log(temp);
}
```

Here is another sample test case.

```
{
    var temp='12345678';
    var format='x-$2';
    temp= temp.replace(/(x*)([0-9]+)/, format);
    console.log(temp);
}
```

Comment: Use regex101.com for such purposes! I've tested the regex and it works properly. See [here](https://regex101.com/r/2Hz0dZ/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(x*)([0-9]+)
 |    |
 g1   g2
```

- `(x*)` - Matches `x` character zero or more time.
- `([0-9]+)` - Matches digits one more time.

So it will replace all any number ( means it can be zero also) of `x` followed by digits, with `format ( x-$2 )` variable.

`g1` - will be replaced with `x`.

`g2` - will be replace with whatever `[0-9]+` matches

```js
var temp='xxxx5678';
var format='x-$2';
temp= temp.replace(/(x*)([0-9]+)/, format);
console.log(temp);
```

Comment: I think you should also mention that `$2` in the format gets filled with the second group of the regex match.

Comment: @Code Maniac Thnx for the clarification !!

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote the code and add notes on Javascript. It would be more clear to learn Javascript replace code and Regex.

```js
var str ='xxxx5678';
result = str.replace(/(x*)([0-9]+)/,'x-$2');
console.log(result);

// str.replace('matech text','replace to')
// (x*)([0-9]+) means two groups $1 and $2. Therefor $2 = ([0-9]+).
// x-$2  replace any string matched (x*)([0-9]+) to "x-" and ([0-9]+).
```